# I'm using Ethernet to USB-C adapter. Will it still work if I disconnect the wireless card?

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet

I'm not a hardware person so please bear with me.

My laptop (Acer 3) has only a wireless module (card?) but I need ethernet, so have one of those ethernet adapters that plugs into the USB-C port.

I want to physically disconnect the wireless for security reasons. The internal wireless gizmo is easy enough to unplug, but ...
is it needed for the ethernet connectivity, or do those adapters have their own ethernet functionality that's independent of the internal wireless module?

Comment: What specifically are you referring to as the “wireless gizmo”?

Comment: @Ramhound The WiFi card, we suppose. Considering the other question I guess this is what should be expected.

Comment: I will patiently wait for the author to clarify

Comment: Sorry for delay. By 'gizmo' I mean yes the wireless ... module? adapter? (looks something like this https://www.newegg.com/acer-america-t77h348-02-hf/p/1B4-0018-004T7)  which attaches to a ribbon cable which is easy to slide off.

Answer (score 1):

Ethernet on a USB(c) adapter works the same way as built in Ethernet. I use this on 2 Lenovo X1 Laptops without built in Ethernet.

**Yes, this will work with wireless disconnected.** The two devices are independent.

With the standard network metric, Wireless will disconnect when Ethernet is active.

I have a USB Wireless Card for my Kali VM.  Ethernet is built in and must be disconnected to use the Wireless but then it works fine.

That is, I use both Ethernet and Wireless on USB and they are entirely interchangeable.

Comment: Great news, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> The internal wireless gizmo is easy enough to unplug, but ... is it needed for the ethernet connectivity, or do those adapters have their own ethernet functionality that's independent of the internal wireless module?

Wi-Fi and Ethernet are both networking technologies but that's the only common feature.

OF COURSE they're independent.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks.